# (UE4) Streaming Level crash when re-entering

Tags: loading, unreal-engine4

I've been having some trouble with streaming levels in my packaged game. My game works fine in editor and I can load into the streaming level (Steaming Usage is SVB Visibility Blocking on Load), see everything, walk out of the streaming level, and walk back in with no problems.

However, When I package my game, I load into the streaming level fine, exit the streaming level, but when I try to re-enter, my game crashes with a Fatal Error like this:

[image: https://answers.unrealengine.com/storage/temp/298425-untitled.png]

The error led me to believe it was having an issue loading one of the assets in the streaming level, so I removed everything from the streaming level and I still got the error message. I tried re-making the project and migrating the assets over from the original project but I still got an error. I was startring to thinik that it might be an issue with version 4.21 but after updating to 4.24, I still got the error.

The error is sometimes different with "Access Violation" so I thought it could be a driver issue so I updated my drivers (with clean install) but the error keeps happening.

I then tried to run the debugger and attach it to my game, I downloaded the ue4 debug symbols and attached VS to my game while it was running, unfortunately I didn't get much from it, here is a screenshot:

[image]

Running out of ideas and I'm not sure what to try next. Perhaps this is a known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out.

The first issue is that in 4.21, the error log was not showing the actual reason for the crash, so I had nothing to go on. I upgraded to 4.24 (which lead to some other problems but not as bad) and created a debug build in 4.24. When I ran the packaged game, it crashed in the same spot as usual however, the log now told me where the issue was and what it was.

In my level blueprint, I had logic for loading a video at runtime, what seems to be happening is it cant find the video quick enough during the level stream load and thus was causing the crash. Once I removed the call to load the video file in the level blueprint, the issue went away.